# Installing RVM as multi-user from a shell script

Tags: shell, rvm

```
OS: Ubuntu 14.04
```

I am trying to install RVM as multi user from a shell script, I have the following in the shell script:

```
gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3
sudo curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

When I run the script, I get the following:

```
Installing RVM to /home/ubuntu/.rvm/
```

When I'm expexting to see:

```
    Installing RVM to /usr/local/rvm
```

The advice on stackoverflow is to install it as sudo, but this is not working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `sudo` on the wrong half of the command.

You need it on the `bash` half not the `curl` half.

You want a `sudo`-ed shell not a `sudo`-ed download.

```
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | sudo bash -s stable
```